# Does Fifa 13 on iPhone allow you to play in Champions League or Europa League in manager mode?

Tags: ios, fifa-13

I have the game on my iPhone, for which I paid only 5 bucks. My question is, in manager mode, do I also get the opportunity to play in Champions League or Europa League? Are these tournaments added in for the iPhone version of the game?

Answer (score -1):

You can qualify for the Champions League. I don't know about Europa Cup, however.